# can this flash effect can be achieved with a lighter form of scripting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash

I have [this](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/images/stories/header_v8.swf) flash header in my website. On older computers the flash file askes a lot of recourses and that is not considered user friendly. Can this effect be achieved in a other way of scripting for example  with ajax or Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible using jQuery. Searching for "mac dock jquery" on Google provided many examples of similar effects implemented using jQuery. (The effect in your swf reminded me of the Mac Dock.)

- http://www.ndesign-studio.com/demo/css-dock-menu/css-dock.html
- http://www.aplweb.co.uk/jQuery/Mac_Dock_v2/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-os-x-style-dock-and-stack-navigation/
- http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/

Not quite the same as the effect in your swf, but close. It's at least evidence that this is possible in pure JavaScript. If you're concerned whether lower-end computers can handle the JavaScript, you can always run one of the above samples and see what happens. It will give you an idea of the performance before you implement your own.

Comment: it's indeed nice, never thought about the mac dock :-) good thinking. this way you can add more images. :)

Answer (score 1):

At least 90% achievable for implementing in Javascript. But the problem is using Javascript could be even more demanding than Flash.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of work you could use Raphael.js see http://raphaeljs.com/

I am a big timer "Flasher" but I am now moving to Raphael, it is really nice and you would be able to achieve these effects in nearly every browser (including iPad and iPhone and IE). When it doesnt work if you do it right, it will just degrade to HTML (I use JS to basically read the HTML divs content eg, links and images and turn these into images using Rapheal).

If you worked with Flash before you will be really surprised how good Rapheal is to work with.  Currently my favourite and cross platform pretty solid.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the raphael library. it seems cool for some animation arts

Answer (score 0):

Well Flash is known for its eating up CPUs. I enter many websites with about 8 flash ads and my CPU is about 100%. Maybe the code for your flash files is poor (no offense!) and I think it can be more user-friendly if you implement it in Flex since Flex has a lot of new improved controls which can help you there.

Comment: I wouldn't know how, i read something about actionscript 2 used means rewrite whole fla.

Comment: I would say that when you visit sites with many animated ads, the ads are the problem, not Flash. Animation, as long as it is not GPU accelerated, will tax your CPU a lot, regardless of (web) technology used. Now when more and more examples of animation on the web is done with other technologies than Flash, this is becoming more and more obvious. See for example http://thewildernessdowntown.com or http://peternitsch.net/demo/battery_test/gasket_html5.html or http://lab.simurai.com/html5/ads/